# In which cases, the TCP checksum will not detect an error?

Tags: tcp, checksum

I have a question related to computer networks, the question is in which of the following case the TCP checksum will not find an error:

**1)** a single bit flip occurs in the 10th byte (i.e., one bit in the 10th byte goes from `0` to `1`, or from `1` to `0`)

**2)** the first byte of the payload that was originally `00000001` becomes `00000000` and the third byte of the payload that was originally `00000000` becomes `00000001`

**3)** the third bit of the first byte of the payload flips from `1` to `0`, AND the third bit of the second byte of the payload flips from `0` to `1`

**4)** the first byte of the payload that was originally `00000001` becomes `00000000`,  and the second byte of the payload that was originally `00000000` becomes `00000001`

Comment: This is not in the scope of SO.

Comment: @zubergu Computing the TCP checksum is a network programming task.

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni I find it disputable. Flagged, see what happens. No point in argument over such long time dead topic anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a TCP checksum fail to detect an error? If yes, how is this dealt with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830206/can-a-tcp-checksum-fail-to-detect-an-error-if-yes-how-is-this-dealt-with)

Answer (score 0):

[RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793) says:

> The checksum field is the 16 bit one's complement of the one's
> complement sum of all 16 bit words in the header and text.

**1)** A single bit flip change the checksum.

**2)** As the sum is on 16 bit words, this will leave the checksum unchanged.

**3)** The two bit changes will not sum up and will change the checksum.

**4)** Same as 3)

**Only the second case will leave the checksum unchanged.**