# Sending variable sized packets over the network using TCP/IP

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, tcp

I want to send variable sized packets between 2 linux OSes over an internal network. The packet is variable sized and its length and CRC are indicated in the header which is also sent along with the packet. Something roughly like-

```
struct hdr {
    uint32 crc;
    uint32 dataSize;
    void *data;
};
```

I'm using CRC at the application layer to overcome the inherent [limitation of TCP checksums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830206/can-a-tcp-checksum-produce-a-false-positive-if-yes-how-is-this-dealt-with)

The problem I have is, there is a chance that the `dataSize` field itself is corrupted, in which case, I dont know where the next packet starts? Cos at the reciver, when I read the socket buffer, I read `n` such packets next to one another. So `dataSize` is the only way I can get to the next packet correctly.

Some ideas I have is to-

1. Restart the connection if a CRC mismatch occurs.
2. Aggregate `X` such packets into one big packet of fixed size and discard the big packet if any CRC error is detected. The big packet is to make sure we lose <= sizeof of one packet in case of errors

Any other ideas for these variable sized packets?

Answer (score 1):

Since TCP is stream based, data length is the generally used way to extract one full message for processing at the application. If you believe that the length byte itself is wrong for some reason, there is not much we can do except discard the packet,"flush" the connection and expect that the sender and receiver would re-sync. But the best is to disconnect the line unless, there is a protocol at the application layer to get to re-sync the connection.

Another method other than length bytes would be to use markers. Start-of-Message and End-of-Message. Application when encountering Start-of-Message should start collecting data until End-of-Message byte is received and then further process the message. This requires that the message escapes the markers appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are dealing with second order error possibilities, when major risk is somewhere else.

When we used serial line transmissions, errors were *frequent* (one or two every several kBytes). We used good old Kermit with a CRC and a packet size of about 100 bytes and that was enough: I encountered many times a failed transfer because the line went off, but never a correct transfer with a bad file.

With current networks, unless you have very very poor lines, the hardware level is not that bad, and anyway the level 2 data link layer already has a checksum to control that each packet was not modified between 2 nodes. HDLC is commonly used at that level and it uses normaly a CRC16 or CRC32 checksum which is a very correct checksum.

So the checksum as TCP level is not meant to detect random errors in the byte stream, but simply as a last defense line for **unexpected** errors, for exemple if a router gets mad because of an electrical shock and sends full garbage. I do not have any statistical data on it, but I am pretty sure that the number of errors reaching the TCP level is already very very low. Said differently, do not worry about that: unless you are dealing with highly sensitive data - and in that case I would prefere to have two different channels, former for data, latter for a global checksum - TCP/IP is enough.

That being said, adding a control at the application level as an ultime defense is perfectly acceptable. It will only process the errors that could have been undetected at data link and TCP level, or more probably errors in the peer application (who wrote it and how was it tested?). So the probability to get an error is low enough to use a very rough recovery procedure:

- close the connection
- open a new one
- restart after last packet correctly exchanged (if it makes sense) or simply continue sending new packets if you can

But the risk is much higher to get a physical disconnection, or a power outage anywhere in the network, not speaking in a flaw in application level implementations...

And do not forget to fully specify the byte order and the size of the crc and datasize...